# Mutable to immutable object

Tags: cocoa

Is there a way to convert mutable object converted to immutable one in cocoa?
I have used NSMutableDictionary *mut=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: copyItems:];
But this dictionary is used in many other places without the mutable thing.

Best Regards,
Subrat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (given your later comment), you want to convert an immutable copy of an mutable object back to being mutable again.

The problem seems to be this:

```
NSMutableString *foo = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"a mutable object"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary1, *dictionary2;

dictionary1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:foo forKey:@"foo"];
dictionary2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dictionary1
               copyItems: YES];

[[dictionary1 objectForKey:@"foo"] appendString:@", mutated"];
[[dictionary2 objectForKey:@"foo"] appendString:@", mutated"];
```

we can alter the object in dictionary1 just fine, but doing the same to dictionary2 throws an exception.

This is because although NSMutableDictionary's initWithDictionary:copyItems: method makes a mutable copy of the dictionary object, it makes immutable copies of its contents.

Classes that distinguish between immutable and immutable versions (such as cocoa's basic string, array & dictionary classes) are supposed to implement a copyWithZone: and mutableCopyWithZone: method. Since not all classes implement an mutableCopyWithZone: method, NSMutableDictionary's initWithDictionary:copyItems: method copies each of dictionary1's contents immutably, meaning that dictionary2 contains immutable objects.

You can make an mutable copy of an immutable object by sending it a mutableCopy message. But probably a better solution for you would be to add an initWithDictionary:mutableCopyItems: method to NSMutableDictionary with a category:

```
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary
      mutableCopyItems:(BOOL)flag
{
 if (flag) {
  self = [self init];

  if (self)
   for (id key in otherDictionary){
    id object = [otherDictionary objectForKey:key];
    if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopyWithZone:)])
     [self setObject:[object mutableCopy] forKey:key];
    else
     [self setObject:[object copy] forKey:key];
   }
 }
 else
  self = [self initWithDictionary:otherDictionary];

 return self;
}
```

Read these if you want to know the difference between copy, mutableCopy, copyWithZone: and mutableCopyWithZone:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSMutableCopying

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying

Answer (score 7):

NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:

Comment: OK let me pour in more details. I have a list of NSMutableDictionary. I am copying a NSMUtableDictinary and putting it in the list as a new entry. But whenever I do some changes in the copied one, the changes are reflected in the original one too. For this tried using NSMutableDictionary *mut=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: copyItems:]; But this too does not work. Once the dictinary is copied, I am unable to perform operation on one of the values of the dictianry later because of mutable to immutable conversion thing. Is there any way out?

Answer (score 3):

This may be an overly simplistic answer, but:

```
NSMutableDictionary * mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithStuff....];
NSDictionary * dictionary = mutableDictionary;
//from this point on, only use dictionary
```

While `dictionary` is *technically* (internally) mutable, you won't be able to access the `set` methods, since those are methods on `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: Isn't this not true though if dictionary is casted to a NSMutableDictionary, like so: (NSMutableDictionary*)dictionary

Comment: this is not true. NSMutableDictionary casted to dictionary IS able to process mutable methods, only the compiler won't let you do so...but you can performSelector or other stuff. This approach could be dangerous if you need this dictionary immutable (for example if you store it and assume values won't change)